# Ubuntu 15.10, hangs after suspend/resume. Inspiron 7559

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, suspend, inspiron

After much toil getting Ubuntu 15.10 setup on my Dell Inspiron 7559, I'm now working through an issue or two.

The main reason I'm trying out Ubuntu (im normally a fedora guy) is because Fedora has been failing me on some hardware related things.  One of them being suspend.  A laptop that you cant suspend is a bit of a pain.  I have to shut down whenever I want to toss the laptop into my bag to head to a meeting or something.  Ubuntu appears to handle this better.  Fedora does too on other hardware, but ubuntu's live usb appeared to suspend/resume just fine on my laptop.

So here I am, fully installed.  I had to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers, following another suggestion I found here.  That's all squared away.

The problem I'm facing now is, when I suspend the system, whether by closing the lid, or by selecting suspend from the upper right gear/power menu, it will suspend just fine.  The system goes to sleep.  The problem is, it wont resume without a crash.  The keyboard lights back up.  The power light comes back on, the screen comes back, but most of the time it doesnt even give me the GUI, or even a mouse cursor, it will either stay black (but powered on/back-lit) or just show me a kernel dump on the screen.  At this point I have to hard power off the system.

/var/log/syslog gives me a lot of output at the time of the crash. There is a lot of repeated data, I've tried to trim it down a bit. The trace at the end repeats over and over until i power off the system.

```
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  sleeping...
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  (wlp5s0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas kernel: [  783.101342] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  (wlp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1131
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  (wlp5s0): DHCPv4 state changed bound -> done
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas kernel: [  783.120592] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from 84:1b:5e:f5:2e:44 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas wpa_supplicant[879]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=84:1b:5e:f5:2e:44 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas avahi-daemon[807]: Withdrawing address record for 10.1.1.109 on wlp5s0.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas avahi-daemon[807]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp5s0.IPv4 with address 10.1.1.109.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas avahi-daemon[807]: Interface wlp5s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas avahi-daemon[807]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::e294:67ff:fe7f:6557 on wlp5s0.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas avahi-daemon[807]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp5s0.IPv6 with address fe80::e294:67ff:fe7f:6557.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas avahi-daemon[807]: Interface wlp5s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas whoopsie[789]: [08:06:26] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas whoopsie[789]: [08:06:26] offline
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas dnsmasq[1164]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas whoopsie[789]: [08:06:26] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas whoopsie[789]: [08:06:26] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: (NetworkManager:820): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 166 was not found when attempting to remove it
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas wpa_supplicant[879]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  (enp4s0): device state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas dbus[774]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas dbus[774]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'down' for wlp5s0
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <warn>  Failed to GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected: disconnect.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas wpa_supplicant[879]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas systemd-sleep[2215]: Suspending system...
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas kernel: [  783.382862] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas kernel: [  783.436910] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
Mar 20 08:06:26 meliodas kernel: [  783.438509] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  784.324517] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  784.326339] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  784.327448] PM: Suspending system (mem)
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  784.327464] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  784.340215] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  784.340266] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  784.984028] PM: suspend of devices complete after 643.969 msecs
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.004026] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 19.997 msecs
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.010195] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.024394] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 20.369 msecs
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.024633] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.068112] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.068113] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.068125] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.069383] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.089516] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.105457] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.121424] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.141344] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.161303] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.180219] Broke affinity for irq 124
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.181253] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.198463] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.198546] ACPI : EC: EC started
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.198546] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.199314] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.199346] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.199347] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.215109]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.215189] CPU1 is up
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.215202] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.227107]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.227173] CPU2 is up
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.227184] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.243125]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.243189] CPU3 is up
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.243199] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.259154]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.259219] CPU4 is up
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.259229] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.271193]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.271257] CPU5 is up
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.271267] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.287187]  cache: parent cpu6 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.287251] CPU6 is up
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.287260] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.307205]  cache: parent cpu7 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.307270] CPU7 is up
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.313401] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.606946] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.607006] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 80.041 msecs
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.621162] PM: early resume of devices complete after 14.123 msecs
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.622460] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.622954] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.662098] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 4 resume PLC timeout
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.679103] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 1 resume PLC timeout
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.679280] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.939020] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  785.950985] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  786.051285] usb 1-2: reset low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  786.329190] usb 1-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  786.439200] usb 1-5: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  786.567205] usb 1-5: device firmware changed
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  786.659098] [drm] RC6 on
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  786.679046] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  787.590724] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc3f tx timeout
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  788.613071] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  789.590423] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc3f tx timeout
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  795.589503] Bluetooth: hci0: turning off Intel device LED failed (-110)
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.565383] Bluetooth: hci0: turning off Intel device LED failed (-61)
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.565438] PM: resume of devices complete after 10945.916 msecs
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.566172] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.566175] Restarting tasks ... done.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas rtkit-daemon[1103]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas rtkit-daemon[1103]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1404]: Time has been changed
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas rtkit-daemon[1103]: Successfully demoted thread 1783 of process 1743 (n/a).
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas rtkit-daemon[1103]: Successfully demoted thread 1782 of process 1743 (n/a).
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas rtkit-daemon[1103]: Successfully demoted thread 1743 of process 1743 (n/a).
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas rtkit-daemon[1103]: Demoted 3 threads.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas acpid: client 915[0:0] has disconnected
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd-sleep[2215]: System resumed.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  waking up...
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  (wlp5s0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  (enp4s0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit is bound to inactive unit systemd-suspend.service. Stopping, too.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs at resume.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.605708] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.606285] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas NetworkManager[820]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.619319] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.619388] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas acpid: client connected from 915[0:0]
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas bluetoothd[783]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas bluetoothd[783]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0...
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas kernel: [  796.709300] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 4
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Mar 20 08:06:50 meliodas systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.821229] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877150] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000000002035
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877199] IP: [<ffffffff811de91a>] kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x7a/0x1f0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877230] PGD 26542e067 PUD 265420067 PMD 0 
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877242] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877251] Modules linked in: rfcomm bbswitch(OE) bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(POE) drbg ansi_cprng dm_crypt nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) arc4 iwlmvm mac80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek i2c_designware_platform snd_hda_codec_generic dell_wmi i2c_designware_core sparse_keymap mxm_wmi intel_rapl dell_laptop snd_hda_intel dcdbas uvcvideo x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_codec intel_powerclamp iwlwifi snd_hda_core coretemp dell_smm_hwmon snd_hwdep kvm_intel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops kvm videobuf2_core snd_pcm cfg80211 v4l2_common videodev snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul btusb media btrtl snd_rawmidi crc32_pclmul btbcm btintel aesni_intel snd_seq bluetooth aes_x86_64 lrw snd_seq_device gf128mul snd_timer glue_helper joydev ablk_helper snd cryptd soundcore idma64 input_leds serio_raw virt_dma shpchp mei_me processor_thermal_device mei intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss_acpi acpi_als intel_soc_dts_iosf wmi intel_lpss dell_rbtn int3402_thermal int3403_thermal int3400_thermal kfifo_buf int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel industrialio acpi_pad mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid i915 i2c_algo_bit psmouse drm_kms_helper r8169 drm ahci mii libahci i2c_hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint hid pinctrl_intel video
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877871] CPU: 1 PID: 1610 Comm: unity-settings- Tainted: P           OE   4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877918] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7559/0H0CC0, BIOS 1.0.4 10/05/2015
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877934] task: ffff880271e45880 ti: ffff880272c20000 task.ti: ffff880272c20000
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877950] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff811de91a>]  [<ffffffff811de91a>] kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x7a/0x1f0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.877988] RSP: 0018:ffff880272c23c18  EFLAGS: 00010206
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878018] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00000000000080d0 RCX: 0000000000007adb
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878064] RDX: 0000000000007ada RSI: 00000000000080d0 RDI: 0000000000019a60
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878079] RBP: ffff880272c23c58 R08: ffff880281c59a60 R09: ffffffff81369d8b
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878095] R10: 8080808080808080 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00000000000080d0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878110] R13: ffff880279003c00 R14: 0000000000002035 R15: ffff880279003c00
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878139] FS:  00007f27e5ce6a00(0000) GS:ffff880281c40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878174] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878205] CR2: 0000000000002035 CR3: 000000026cd28000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878250] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878266] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878294] Stack:
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878299]  ffffffff81369d8b 0000000000000018 0100000100010000 ffff880279091430
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878316]  ffff8800673aa200 ffff880272c23eec 0000000000000001 ffff880272c23db8
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878352]  ffff880272c23c88 ffffffff81369d8b ffff880272c23d28 ffffffff811ff4dc
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878387] Call Trace:
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878409]  [<ffffffff81369d8b>] ? apparmor_file_alloc_security+0x5b/0x150
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878441]  [<ffffffff81369d8b>] apparmor_file_alloc_security+0x5b/0x150
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878484]  [<ffffffff811ff4dc>] ? get_empty_filp+0x5c/0x1c0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878497]  [<ffffffff81327df3>] security_file_alloc+0x33/0x50
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878510]  [<ffffffff811ff51a>] get_empty_filp+0x9a/0x1c0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878566]  [<ffffffff8120bc8d>] path_openat+0x3d/0x12c0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878615]  [<ffffffff8120d519>] ? filename_lookup+0xe9/0x180
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878629]  [<ffffffff8120d08b>] ? putname+0x5b/0x60
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878642]  [<ffffffff8120e10a>] do_filp_open+0x8a/0x100
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878655]  [<ffffffff81202ea6>] ? cp_new_stat+0x156/0x190
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878681]  [<ffffffff811dee77>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x187/0x200
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878695]  [<ffffffff8121b946>] ? __alloc_fd+0x46/0x110
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878707]  [<ffffffff811fcbb8>] do_sys_open+0x138/0x280
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878719]  [<ffffffff811fcd1e>] SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878731]  [<ffffffff817f2cf2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878763] Code: 65 4c 03 05 81 b8 e2 7e 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 30 0f 84 2b 01 00 00 4d 85 f6 0f 84 22 01 00 00 49 63 45 20 48 8d 4a 01 49 8b 7d 00 <49> 8b 1c 06 4c 89 f0 65 48 0f c7 0f 0f 94 c0 84 c0 74 b9 49 63 
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878894] RIP  [<ffffffff811de91a>] kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x7a/0x1f0
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878909]  RSP <ffff880272c23c18>
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.878917] CR2: 0000000000002035
Mar 20 08:06:51 meliodas kernel: [  796.886317] ---[ end trace b357a118c30bd8f0 ]---
```

Comment: it would seem that this issue is more intermittent than I thought.  In some cases, the system will recover from suspend.  It seems like if i close the lid, to initiate a suspend, and then open the lid again too soon, it crashes.  However in many (not all) cases, if i just give the system about a minute before I re-open the lid, it resumes.  Under normal use you wouldnt be closing/opening the lid so rapidly, so this may be livable.  But it's still a gamble whether it's going to resume or not. Even if i wait.

Comment: Hey ? Did you manage the solve the problem ? There's a temporary workaround on the problem @ nvidia-378 i.e. keep it plugged in/ on charge and it won't crash!